# How to reposition Albums into correct place in hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hierarchy, flickr, nested-sets

This is complicated to understand but I really will do my best at explaining what i'm trying to do.

I need help in trying to figure out how to achieve a result. Not necessarily the code to do it but working out the steps I need to take.

I have a set of Photos on Flickr.   They are organised (using Flickr's terminology) into PhotoSets and Collections.

An example Structure:

DEMO 1:

```
2023 (Collection)
  - Trip 1 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 2 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 3 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 4 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 5 (PhotoSet)
  - Trip 2 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 2 (PhotoSet)
    - Day 3 (PhotoSet)
  - Miscellaneous (Collection)
    - Random Day out 1 (PhotoSet)
    - Random Day out 2 (PhotoSet)
    - Random Day out 3 (PhotoSet)
    - Random Day out 4 (PhotoSet)
```

This is fine, BUT in my Rails app, I have a gallery that i'm working on and i'd like to display Collections and some Photosets at the same level.  The PhotoSets that should be displayed at the same level are those in the "Miscellaneous" Collection.

This is fine up until now. I've written a script to import this data into my app and I use my own terminology here (Collections and PhotoAlbums).

As part of the import script, if a Collection has the name "Miscellaneous", I don't create a Collection and just create the PhotoAlbums it contained and I set the parent of them to the previous parent.  The local hierarchy then looks like:

DEMO 2:

```
2023 (Collection)
  - Trip 1 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 4 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 5 (PhotoAlbum)
  - Trip 2 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum)
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum)
  - Random Day out 1 (PhotoAlbum)
  - Random Day out 2 (PhotoAlbum)
  - Random Day out 3 (PhotoAlbum)
  - Random Day out 4 (PhotoAlbum)
```

The problem then starts here:

It turns out that i'd like these to be displayed in chronological order.  I'll mark the order using letters:

DEMO 3:

```
2023 (Collection)
  - Trip 1 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum) C
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum) D
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum) E
    - Day 4 (PhotoAlbum) F
    - Day 5 (PhotoAlbum) G
  - Trip 2 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum) I
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum) J
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum) K
  - Random Day out 1 (PhotoAlbum) A
  - Random Day out 2 (PhotoAlbum) B
  - Random Day out 3 (PhotoAlbum) H
  - Random Day out 4 (PhotoAlbum) L
```

Therefore I wish to end up with a hierarchy in my app like:

DEMO 4:

```
2023 (Collection)
  - Random Day out 1 (PhotoAlbum) A
  - Random Day out 2 (PhotoAlbum) B
  - Trip 1 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum) C
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum) D
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum) E
    - Day 4 (PhotoAlbum) F
    - Day 5 (PhotoAlbum) G
  - Random Day out 3 (PhotoAlbum) H
  - Trip 2 (Collection)
    - Day 1 (PhotoAlbum) I
    - Day 2 (PhotoAlbum) J
    - Day 3 (PhotoAlbum) K
  - Random Day out 4 (PhotoAlbum) L
```

On Flickr, I can pull a list of all my PhotoSets and they are in A-L order, but when I pull through the hierarchy, it returns them as in my first demo list.

This would all not be necessary if Flickr allowed us to put Collections AND PhotoSets at the same level but alas they don't.

What I need help with is how to transition from DEMO 2 to DEMO 4.

I'm not really sure what else to add.  I've done my best to explain my problem as clearly and efficiently as possible.  I'd like to see how people suggest I go about resolving this and coming up with a solution.

Comment: You have thoroughly explained your problem however we have no idea what attributes are related to a `Collection` or a `PhotoSet`, nor how you are displaying them, how you have obtained DEMO 2, how we can identify them as A-L, or any additional relevant information in that regard. For Example what let's us know that  "Random Day out 1 (PhotoAlbum)" should come before "Random Day out 2" or "Trip 1"?

Comment: @engineersmnky I think you missed this: "It turns out that i'd like these to be displayed in chronological order. I'll mark the order using letters"

Comment: @rctneil are you able to get the timestamps from Flickr? Just store those in your DB as well, and use them to order the list.

Comment: @smathy I didn't miss that at all, I just have no information as to chronology in this case. Given that no portion of the post provides a date or a time chronological completely ambiguous. How do you know "Random Day out 3" comes between "Trip 1 Day 5" and "Trip 2 Day 1"? It could just as easily fall anywhere else.

Comment: @engineersmnky OP just used the letters to show the chronology ordering. No actual timestamps, but A is chronologically ordered before B, etc.

Comment: thanks Both. The order of PhotoSets that I have is determined by me dragging and dropping them in a specific order in the Flickr organiser. I have added the PhotoSet order in my app but can’t sort by it as this is where the issue lies. I need to move the Collections into the position of where the first child PhotoSet is.  I’m struggling to do that with the hierarchical gem I’ve used ‘awesome-nested-set’. I’ll post my code tomorrow.   The letters just indicate the order of the Sets at Flickr and then the order I want them in my app.

Comment: @engineersmnky @smathy I think the problem is that, `awesome_nested_set` has `move_to_child_of`, `move_to_left_of` and `move_to_right_of` methods. I cannot identify which Collections need moving order programatically. Therefore what happens to one needs to happen to them all.  I can iterate over them, but i need a foolproof way of moving them to where the first of their child PhotoAlbums currently is.  If I try to do that, `awesome_nested_set` says it's impossible (because it's effectively me asking it to put a parent inside itself).

Comment: There some great comments here already, but let me add my own. Flickr models data in a certain way, you like it or not. You will have a very bad time trying to model data otherwise, when all your data is directly dependent on Flickr. Try to find a way to model it similar to what Flickr does, will lead to way less frustration

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Oh I absolutely understand that I am trying to model things in a different way to Flickr.  That being I wish to have both Albums and Collections as children of Collections whereas this is forbidden at Flickr (and for good reason!).  I have managed to come up with a solution, albeit it being a little round the houses.  As long as I can keep the logic that does that in one messy method out the way I should be ok.  If it does eventually fall over then I can go back to just displaying the "Misc" Collection as Flickr wishes.